# Como unir duas tabelas usando tabela auxiliar e LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, loop

Tenho as tabelas Pessoas e Representantes, onde na minha aplicação a pessoa pode ou não ter representante(s).

```
public  class Conta
{
    int PessoaID;
    string Nome;
    String Documento;
}
public  class Representante
{
    int RepresentanteID;
    int PessoaID.    
    string Nome;
    String Documento;
}
```

Baseado nisso tenho uma terceira tabela, onde traz Representantes das Pessoas

```
ID     PessoaID    RepID
1        8                   2
2        8                   3
3        10                 5
4        11                 6
```

Baseado neste esquema eu gero um contrato onde eu falo da Pessoa, que pegarei com o PessoaID e Os Representantes pelo campo RepID para colocar no contrato, caso o cliente tenha algum ou mais de 1 representantes.

Eu acho que a melhor maneira de representar isso seria com o String.Format(). Agora supondo que eu tenha uma pessoa e ela tenha 3 reprentantes, como eu faria isso em C#? Eu sei que preciso executar um laço mas não sei como monta-lo baseado nesse modelo que preciso, e ainda mais: Acho que estou usando código demais.

Aqui esta parte do que eu fiz:

```
var pessoa = (from p in db.Pessoas
where pPessoaID == pessoaid
select p).SingleOrDefault();

var representante = (from p in db.Representantes
where p.RepID == repid
select p).SingleOrDefault();

var contrato = from p in db.Contrato
where p.PessoaID == pessoa.PessoaID
select p;
```

A pergunta é: Como eu faço para pegar a pessoa de ID 8 e seus representantes e colocá-los no contrato

Comment: Por favor, coloque também as classes (models) `Pessoas`, `Representantes`, `Contrato` na pergunta.

Comment: @MurariAlex eu fiz via Linq to SQL, Editei acima parte da tabela como ela é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz a query em `LINQ` que obtém as pessoas e representantes através da tabela que une representantes a pessoas, fiz umas alterações de estilo na sua classe para que ela fique num padrão mais conciso.

**Query LINQ**

```
// representantePessoa, pessoa e representante são 
// os objetos que contém as listas das pessoas representantes, etc..

var contratos = (from rp in representantePessoa
                join p in pessoa on rp.PessoaId equals p.PessoaId
                join r in representante on rp.RepresentanteId equals r.RepresentanteId
                // where rp.PessoaId == algumaVariavel
                select new
                {
                    NomePessoa = p.Nome,
                    DocumentoPessoa = p.Documento,
                    NomeRepresentante = r.Nome,
                    DocumentoRepresentante = r.Documento
                }).ToList();

// Para exibir basta acessar os objetos dentro de um `foreach` 
// ou LINQ como se fosse um objeto comum.

foreach (var contrato in contratos)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Nome: {0}, Documento {1}, Representante: {2}, Documento Representante: {3}", 
   contrato.NomePessoa, contrato.DocumentoPessoa, contrato.NomeRepresentante, contrato.DocRepresentante));
}
```

Na query acima, estou obtendo a *tabela* `representantePessoa` e unindo (`join`) as tabelas `representante` e `pessoa`, como se fosse uma query SQL comum, e fazendo o select dos nomes e documentos das pessoas e seus respectivos representantes. Não necessita fazer queries em outras tabelas ou criar outros objetos, este já basta, tem todas as informações em um só.
Lembre-se que o resultado será exatamente como de uma query SQL, os nomes das pessoas virão repetidos para cada representante.

Aqui estão as classes que usei:

**Classes**

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }
}

public class Representante
{
    public int RepresentanteId { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }
}

public class RepresentantePessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public int RepresentanteId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @MuriloAlex esse exemplo consegui quase entender. Agora como irei colocar em  prática por exemplo: Claudinei ferreira, documento, Representado por Fulano de Tal, Documento Nº ...

Comment: @ClaudineiFerreira Adicionei um exemplo a minha resposta de como pode exibir.

Comment: Exatamente, fiz aqui e resolveu. Como estou usando Aspnet, usei Label. Obrigado mesmo @Murari